# Querying related data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Im new to the Eloquent ORM and need to query my DB for related data,

i have read the documentation but i can't seem to get it to work for my scenario. I am using the repository pattern.
Here is the relevant parts of my schema:

[image: schema]

What i need to do is get all of the consultant profiles as well as the consultants multiple qualifications, specialties and registrations.

As you can see the related models have the profile id of the consultant in them as a foreign key.

SO using repositories how would i get all the data for every consultant into a single object/array?

Cheers

Comment: Model::with('relation1', 'relation2', 'relation3')->get();

Comment: Hi thanks, i have just got to this point and all working! One of the withs is to a pivot table, so instead of retrieving the ID's in the pivot, how to i retrieve the actual data from the other side of the pivot?

Comment: with is not for pivot, with means that you will load relations in object

Comment: @TomBurman You shouldn't need to define relationships to a pivot table. Just use a [many-to-many relation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many)